# Find common key: value pair in dict for non hashable keys and values

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

i have a list of dictionaries as below:

```
    [{'EchoTime': 0,
      'FlipAngle': 90,
      'MRAcquisitionType': '2D',
      'MagneticFieldStrength': 3,
      'Manufacturer': 'SIEMENS',
      'ManufacturerModelName': 'TrioTim',
      'RepetitionTime': 2,
      'ScanOptions': 'FS',
      'ScanningSequence': 'EP',
      'SequenceName': 'epfid2d1_64',
      'SequenceVariant': 'SK',
      'SliceTiming': [[0.0025000000000000022],
       [0.5],
       [-0.030000000000000027],
       [0.46625],
       [0.168749999995],
       [-0.36124999999999996],
       [-0.46124999999500005],
       [0.036250000005000005]],
      'TaskName': 'tom'},
     {'EchoTime': 0,
      'FlipAngle': 90,
      'MRAcquisitionType': '2D',
      'MagneticFieldStrength': 3,
      'Manufacturer': 'SIEMENS',
      'ScanningSequence': 'EP',
      'SequenceName': 'epfid2d1_64',
      'SequenceVariant': 'SK',
      'SliceTiming': [[0.0037500000050000315],
       [0.5],
       [-0.030000000000000027],
       [0.46750000001500003],
       [-0.0625],
       [0.36750000001],
       [-0.16249999998999998],
       [0.33500000000499996],
       [-0.19499999998999995],
       [0.301250000005]],
      'TaskName': 'tom'},
       {'EchoTime': 0,
  'FlipAngle': 90,
  'MRAcquisitionType': '2D',
  'MagneticFieldStrength': 3,
  'RepetitionTime': 2,
  'ScanOptions': 'FS',
  'ScanningSequence': 'EP',
  'SequenceName': 'epfid2d1_64',
  'SequenceVariant': 'SK',
  'SliceTiming': [[0.0025000000000000022],
   [0.5],
   [-0.030000000000000027],
   [0.46625],
   [-0.19625000000000004],
   [0.301250000005],
   [-0.22875],
   [0.26749999999999996],
   [-0.26249999999500007]],
  'TaskName': 't1'},
  {'EchoTime': 0,
  'FlipAngle': 90,
  'MRAcquisitionType': '2D',
  'Manufacturer': 'SIEMENS',
  'ManufacturerModelName': 'TrioTim',
  'SequenceVariant': 'SK',
  'SliceTiming': [[0.0025000000000000022],
   [0.5],
   [-0.030000000000000027],
   [0.46625],
   [-0.06374999999999997],
   [0.43375000000499997],
   [-0.09624999999999995],
   [0.4],
   [-0.22875],
   [0.26749999999999996],
   [-0.26249999999500007],
   [0.235]],
  'TaskName': 'fb'}]
```

there are about 2000 dict in the list. 
Now i want to find common key: value pair amongst all the dict in the list. 
For the same i used following function:

```
def twodict_intersec(json1, json2):
    d = {x:json1[x] for x in json1 if x in json2}
    return d

for i in range(0,10,1):
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        res = twodict_intersec(json_list[i], json_list[i+1])
    else:
        res = dict_intersect(res, json_list[i+1])
print(res)
```

But the output is something like below where each key contains list of all values instead of common value

```
res = {'EchoTime': [[[[[[[[[0, 0], 0], 0], 0], 0], 0], 0], 0], 0], 'FlipAngle': [[[[[[[[[90, 90], 90], 90], 90], 90], 90], 90], 90], 90], 'ManufacturerModelName': [[[[[[[[['TrioTim', 'TrioTim'], 'TrioTim'], 'TrioTim'], 'TrioTim'], 'TrioTim'], 'TrioTim'], 'TrioTim'], 'TrioTim']}
```

i am not able to get output where each key will have only one value which common in all dict instead of above situation. Can someone point out my mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare all the elements in your dictionary list this way:

```
import copy
li = [{
        "keep this value":5,
        "remove this":59
    },{
        "keep this value":5,
        "remove this":12
    }]

def compareList(li):
    result = copy.deepcopy(li[0])
    for element in li:
        for key in element:
            if key in result and result[key] != element[key]:
                del result[key]
    return result

print (compareList(li))
```

Comment: you mean i need to use this for `result` i am getting from above function?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Remember to upvote and mark as solution, it helps a lot.